# General webserver log and custom logs where to gather them

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx, logging

I am not trying to create an opinionated question here though it might sound like it.
My problem is as follows.

I have the normal apache2 access and error log on a bunch of servers.
I also have custom logs with custom formats.

I have noticed a beginning performance issue due to the amount of lines being written into the log files so I am looking for alternatives.

I would love to somehow gather the log entries. I have been trying to understand how syslog works and I think that's the direction I need to go since the syslog would function as a kind of buffer.

I know of a program called greylog... But I am not sure if that is the direction I should go... Maybe someone have experience on a similar setup and could share how they made it work?

Comment: Have you considered logrotate?

Comment: I am rotating the log via log rotate.. but that doesn't change the issue with a lot of IO... I need some other way of storing the logs...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to log using syslog with Apache's `CustomLog` directive?

For example,

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -t 'httpd'" combined
```

That might help you performance-wise, especially if you tune the syslog daemon itself to write asynchronously. With more fine-grained sysloggers such as `syslog-ng`, you have many performance-related tunables.

Another advantage of this approach would be that this way you could send everything to a centralized log server and let it receive the disk I/O strain instead of your web server.

Comment: No I haven't. I would definitely like to send it to another server for storage. How would I tell the logger to send to another server? And how would the server receive the log entry?

Comment: `logger` is just a messenger, the real "please send this log line to another server" work is done by the syslog daemon your server has. For example, with the traditional `syslogd`, you would send logs to another server with `@someserver` parameter.

The centralized log server then receives the message and puts it in the directory & file it seems best. `syslog-ng` can be kind of plug-and-play solution for your centralized logging; with its templates you can define that logs will be stored in `/var/remote_logs/$hostname/` fashion so you could find your logs per-host basis. :)